# Git does not apply deleted files when merging an old branch into the master. How can I tell Git to apply deleted files?

Tags: git, git-merge

I have a master and a dev branch.
I made commits in both.
I also deleted some files in dev.
I made other commit in master, so this master branch is more recent.

My issue is that merging dev into master dont delete files.

Git consider that these files exists in master and consequently, keep them during the merge.

How can I merge these two branches and force Git to apply all and every commits made in dev ? including deleted files.

Thks for your help!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Interesting, are you using a git application or just from command line?

Comment: I'm using the cmd line

Comment: This is not the way it works for me. Merges definitely delete files when there's not a conflict with changes in branches. You may have a special default [merge strategy](https://git-scm.com/docs/merge-strategies) that produces this behavior.

Comment: Just to reiterate, this is not what git does. git does not preserve files during merging if they are deleted in the to-be-merged branch. You have a different problem.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

*Merges definitely delete files when there's not a conflict with changes in branches.*

> git does not preserve files during merging if they are deleted in the merging branch. - Nils_M

To prove it to myself, I had to try to reproduce your scenario. See this demonstration in hopes that you can see what it is you are doing differently.

## create a new repository

```
mkdir test
cd test
git init
```

> Initialized empty Git repository in /test/.git/

## create and add some files to master branch

```
echo one > 1.txt
echo two > 2.txt
git add .
git commit -m "init repo"
```

> [master (root-commit) feaa910] init repo
>    2 files changed, 2 insertions(+)
>    create mode 100644 1.txt
>    create mode 100644 2.txt

## create new branch and add/delete some files

```
git checkout -b new
```

> Switched to a new branch 'new'

```
echo three > 3.txt
rm 2.txt 
git add .
git status
```

> On branch new
>   Changes to be committed:
>     (use "git reset HEAD ..." to unstage)
>
> deleted:    2.txt
>     new file:   3.txt

```
git commit -m "changes in new"
```

> [new db6b1a0] changes in new
>    2 files changed, 1 insertion(+), 1 deletion(-)
>    delete mode 100644 2.txt
>    create mode 100644 3.txt

## commit some more changes in master

```
git checkout master
```

> Switched to branch 'master'

```
echo update >> 1.txt 
git commit -am "update master"
```

> [master 912a520] update master
>    1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)

```
tree
```

> .
>   ├── 1.txt
>   └── 2.txt

## verify files still deleted in new

```
git checkout new
```

> Switched to branch 'new'

```
tree
```

> .
>   ├── 1.txt
>   └── 3.txt

## merge new into master

```
git checkout master
```

> Switched to branch 'master'

```
git merge new master
```

> Removing 2.txt
>   Merge made by the 'recursive' strategy.
>    2.txt | 1 -
>    3.txt | 1 +
>    2 files changed, 1 insertion(+), 1 deletion(-)
>    delete mode 100644 2.txt
>    create mode 100644 3.txt

```
tree
```

> .
>   ├── 1.txt
>   └── 3.txt

as you can see, the file `2.txt` deleted in the `new` branch is now definitely deleted in `master` following the merge.

Comment: Thks for so much efforts to illustrate my issue. 
I agree that this is the default behavior.
Unfortunately, I do have a git merge that don't take deleted files into account.

Answer (score 7):

The only way I can fathom this possible situation is if you created two different files, each with the same filename, in independent branches.

i.e. let's say that the `master` and `dev` branches already exist.

1. create and commit `file.txt` to `master`
2. checkout `dev`, then *again **create*** and commit `file.txt` to `dev`. Now because you have created two distinct files, git views them as two separate entities despite the same filename, defeating the whole purpose of version control.
3. later delete `file.txt` from `dev`
4. merge `dev` into `master`, and low and behold `file.txt` still exists in `master`, and this makes sense because like I said, git views the two files as completely independent.

**notice** if you had *not* deleted `file.txt` from `dev` and attempted a merge, then you would have gotten a merge conflict because git wouldn't know how to handle two different entities with the same path/filename.

If this is your scenario, then I'm going to risk arrogance and say you're doing it wrong ;)

The point of a version control system is to let the tool manage your differences between a file at different stages in time as well as the relationship of those changes to other files in the repository.

My suggestion to improve the workflow in this situation would be to checkout the specific file from the other branch:

1. create and commit `file.txt` to `master`
2. checkout `dev`, then just grab the particular file from the other branch

   ```
   git checkout master -- file.txt
   ```

   In this situation, you will still be on the `dev` branch, but have now added `file.txt` from the `master` branch.
3. now git recognizes that these are the same entity. so you can delete the file and commit the removal in `dev`
4. merging `dev` into `master` will now delete `file.txt` from `master`

Comment: Thanks a lot for these details. I'll try to checkout the deleted files and git merge again. Thk for the tip.

Comment: This has been my problem all along. Same exact file(s) created in different branches at different times and they didn't exist at the base of the diverging branch either. Took me days to realize...

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. In my case I think the problem was that, when I did the merge, my copy of the merged-from branch was outdated compared to the remote. (a colleague had done the deletion, not me)

In any case, what fixed it was deleting the whole working copy and cloning it anew.

Answer (score 0):

You can run the merge without committing, make sure you have all of the correct files, and then run the commit.

1. Perform the merge

   ```
   git checkout master
   git merge --no-commit dev
   ```
2. Make the necessary changes, and fix merge conflicts (if any).

   ```
   git rm my-files-to-delete
   ```
3. Commit the merge, finishing the process.

   ```
   git commit
   ```